# How do I update selective fields in SQL (leaving some unchanged)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameterized

I would like to update a record with two dates, leaving existing data intact if I do not have a new value to update with.

Here is a sample table record:

```
id  last_foo    last_bar
--  ----------  ----------
 1  2010-05-30  2010-05-30
```

And the query I am using:

```
UPDATE sampledates
   SET last_foo = @LastFoo, 
       last_bar = @LastBar
 WHERE id = @ID;
```

If my ***nullable datetimes*** `LastFoo` or `LastBar` are null, I would like to leave the existing SQL value as-is, otherwise update.

For example, say I am updating this record with the following values (this is C# but any language applies):

```
DateTime? LastFoo = new DateTime('2010-06-04');
DateTime? LastBar = null;
```

I would like the record to then be:

```
id  last_foo    last_bar
--  ----------  ----------
 1  2010-06-04  2010-05-30
```

I realize I can alter my query text to omit the second column if the value is null, but I wondered if there is a way I can leave the query as-is and specify that I am not changing the column specified.

Comment: I reviewed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637901/best-practise-when-updating-individual-fields-in-a-database-record but it isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Comment: @Mark: DATETIME means either MySQL or SQL Server, but all the answers provided are agnostic

Comment: This is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: "all the answers provided are agnostic" - not true. Check again. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE sampledates
SET last_foo = COALESCE(@LastFoo,last_foo ), 
last_bar = COALESCE(@LastBar,last_bar )
WHERE id = @ID;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
UPDATE sampledates
SET last_foo = COALESCE(@LastFoo, last_foo),
    last_bar = COALESCE(@LastBar, last_bar)
WHERE id = @ID;
```

In SQL Server you get a minor performance improvement by using [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) instead of COALESCE.

```
UPDATE sampledates
SET last_foo = ISNULL(@LastFoo, last_foo),
    last_bar = ISNULL(@LastBar, last_bar)
WHERE id = @ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the `ISNULL` reference as well. SQLMenace had the same idea a tad earlier, so I picked his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (this is untested, I don't have SSMS available to me right now)

```
UPDATE sampledates
   SET last_foo = CASE WHEN @LastFoo IS NULL THEN last_foo ELSE @LastFoo END, 
       last_bar = CASE WHEN @LastBar IS NULL THEN last_foo ELSE @LastBar END
  WHERE id = @ID;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's faster? COALESCE, ISNULL or CASE logic?

Comment: ISNULL last I have heard. Coalesce is ANSI standard though, and works for more than 1 case. ISNULL only accepts one parameter that can be null, coalesce takes as many as you throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
UPDATE sampledates
SET last_foo = (case when @LastFoo IS NULL then last_foo else @LastFoo end), 
last_bar = (case when @LastBar IS NULL then last_bar else @LastBar end)
WHERE id = @ID;
```