# SQL expression for not changing the field in UPDATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It must be a classic scenario, but I don't see any question for it...
I receive a lot of arguments in HTTP request for updating a row in the database.
Some other parameters are not set.
I am using some C++ framework for the SQL queries.

And I have a query like:

```
auto update(R"__(
UPDATE
  table
SET
  field1 = ?,
  field2 = ?
WHERE
  id = ?
)__");

exec_update(update, {field1.value_or(<?>), field2.value_or(<?>), id})
```

Because there can be around 30 fields to update, I don't want to create the query dynamically, but I would rather use some keyword to tell the Postgresql not to change the fields that I don't have new value for, how to achieve that?
Simply, what to put instead of the `<?>`?

I only found a similar question: [How do I update selective fields in SQL (leaving some unchanged)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978008/how-do-i-update-selective-fields-in-sql-leaving-some-unchanged), which is a special case for this, I want to be able to set even `NULL` or whatever, I just want to not update some fields from the query without changing the query, I want to just have the values dynamic, not the query.

EDIT: I couldn't find anything better than having the dynamic query like:

```
  auto update(fmt::format(
      R"__(
    UPDATE
      table
    SET
      field1 = {},
      field2 = {},
    WHERE
      id = {}
  )__",
      object.get_field1().has_value() ? fmt::format("'{}'", object.get_field1().value())
                                      : "field1",
      object.get_field2().has_value() ? fmt::format("'{}'", object.get_field2().value())
                                      : "field2",
      id));
```

, but I am not much satisfied with that.

Comment: You can either set them to themselves (`column = column`) or not mention them at all.

Comment: I want to mention them, so for example `SET field1 = field1`? that sound easy :D

Comment: I don't know the framework/library but almost certainly you cannot pass identifiers for the parameters (well, you can but they'll get quoted and effectively become string literals), should you have that in mind.

Comment: I guess that's fine, I can hard-code the names of the columns. I think it will work, testing.

Comment: @stickybit How to send it unquoted? :D

Comment: Change the query string and write the column name instead of `?`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222933/discussion-between-lukas-salich-and-sticky-bit).

Comment: Ok, in the end, I did the query dynamic (not happy with it), will post as answer hopefully tomorrow.